# How to render a panel using ajax in submenu primefaces

Tags: ajax, primefaces

I want to render the panel content by the value in the submenu selected .But the panel is not rendered.Is there anyother way to render the panel in submenu

```
<h:panelGroup id="menu" layout="block">
    <h:form>
        <h:outputStylesheet name="css/primefaces.css" />
        <p:growl id="messages" autoUpdate="true" />
        <f:ajax event="click" render=":content">
            <p:panelMenu style="width:200px " styleClass="ui-menubar"
        autoSubmenuDisplay="true">
                <p:submenu label="Ajax ">                   
                    <p:menuitem value="Home" action =                                       "#{menuBar.setPage('menu1.xhtml')}"  />  
                </p:submenu>            
            </p:panelMenu>
        </f:ajax>
    </h:form>
</h:panelGroup>

<h:panelGroup id="content" layout="block" >
    <h:form id="contentform">
        <ui:include src="#{menuBar.page}" />
    </h:form>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: your code look not complete `<p:menuitem value="Home" action =` ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `update` attribute of your `<p:menuitem`

> p:menuitem got **update** and **process** attributes

In general don't mix JSF `f:ajax` with primefaces components and visa versa